# Can I import the result of calculation from other computer language into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, fortran

I try to make a kind of plug-in function in QGIS. The problem is my code is too hard to execute with only Python. The original my code is for Fortran, So I am looking for the method to connect 'QGIS and Fortran', or 'Python and Fortran'. Can  QGIS, or Python import the result of Fortran?

If it is possible, please tell me how I can find the method.

Comment: Can you edit the question to give more detail about what your Fortran script does, or the data it creates?   Did you consider C++ as QGIS plugins don't have to be in Python